# Поиск слов в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, search

В базе есть строка такого вида `a:3:{i:0;s:16:"Женщинам";i:1;s:12:"одежда";i:2;s:14:"Пиджаки";}` т.е функция `php` `serialize` нужно осуществить поиск по словам: `Женщинам` и `Пиджаки` мой запрос в БД ищет эти слова как одно целое и не находит совпадения.

```
$category = 'Женщинам Пиджаки';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product category LIKE :txt";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute( [':txt' => "%{$category}%"] );
return $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Нужно чтобы поиск в данном случае проигнорировал то что между словами Женщинам и Пиджаки.

Comment: Если вам нужно искать по словам, зачем хранить сериализованные данные?

Comment: @vp_arth Это категории, которые используются не только для поиска

Comment: Ну так тем более. Сериализовать можно только те данные, которые не нужны будут по раздельности. Это у вас не категории, а теги какие-то. Для категорий должна быть отдельная таблица со строками `product_id, category_id`

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что у вас не совпадают кодировки. В базе и в запросе. Также стоит добавить кавычки в название категории, чтобы не находить скажем, "Пиджаки с карманами" при поиске "Пиджаки". Ну и главное - найдите слово `WHERE` в Вашем запросе.

Comment: Что Вы передаёте в переменной `$category`?

Comment: @vp_arth `/result?category=Женщинам Пиджаки`

Comment: как на счёт использовать два условия в запросе?!
`WHERE LIKE foo AND LIKE bar`

Comment: А о какой базе идёт речь? mysql?

Comment: @vp_arth Да mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное, что можно подсказать без починки структуры базы - строить запрос динамически:

```
$category = 'Женщинам Пиджаки';
$categories = preg_split('/\s+/', $category);

$likes = array_fill(0, count($categories), 'category LIKE ?');
$likes = '('.implode(' AND ', $likes) .')';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE $likes";
// SELECT * FROM product WHERE (category LIKE ? AND category LIKE ?)

$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array_map(function($cat) {
  return '%"'. $cat . '"%';
}, $categories));

return $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас запрос написан так как вы указали, то он у вас вообще не работает, потому что в нем нет конструкции WHERE.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE :txt";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute( [':txt' => "%{$category}%"] );
return $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Апострофы лишние - с ними `:txt` перестаёт быть плейсхолдером. Я имел в виду `"%\"{$category}\"%"`

Comment: Запрос работает нормально я его здесь корректировал

Comment: @AziretKadykeev, вы просите починить Ваш код, но показываете его "откорректированным"? Зачем?

Comment: @vp_arth "откорретированная" часть не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу